# How to restructure an XML file based on some rules?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jsf-2, facelets

I have thousands of JSP files which are based on JSF1.2 but I want to migrate to JSF2.0 and using facelets instead, so I have to change their structure based on [some defined rules](http://wiki.icesoft.org/display/ICE/Converting+ICEfaces+1.8+Applications+to+ICEfaces+3#ConvertingICEfaces1.8ApplicationstoICEfaces3-step4), for example some of the required changes are as follow:

- I should remove `<view>` tag
- I should convert `<head>` to `<h:head>`
- I should convert `<body>` to `<h:body>`
- I should change some namespace declarations

Because of the huge number of files I decided to develop a mini-application to automate this process otherwise I have to manually modify a lot of files!!

**I was wondering what is the best solution to do so? Should I use XSLT or should I parse the JSP file as an XML file and modify their structure via DOM?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is straight-forward with XSLT.

**Here is an example that performs all required replacements**:

**Given this source XML file**:

```
<html xmlns:old="old:namespace">
 <head>
  <meta property="og:type" content="webcontent"/>
 </head>
 <view>Some View</view>
 <body>
   The Body here.
 </body>
</html>
```

**This transformation carries out all requested changes:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:h="some:h" xmlns:old="old:namespace" xmlns:new="new:new"
 exclude-result-prefixes="h new old">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vnsH" select="document('')/*/namespace::h"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vnsNew" select="document('')/*/namespace::new"/>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()='old')]"/>
   <xsl:if test="namespace::old">
     <xsl:copy-of select="$vnsNew"/>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()[not(self::*)]">
     <xsl:copy/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="view"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()='old')]|$vnsH"/>
   <xsl:if test="namespace::old">
     <xsl:copy-of select="$vnsNew"/>
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="head|body">
  <xsl:element name="h:{name()}" namespace="some:h">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()='old')]"/>
    <xsl:if test="namespace::old">
     <xsl:copy-of select="$vnsNew"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the above XML document, the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<html xmlns:h="some:h" xmlns:new="new:new">
   <h:head>
      <meta property="og:type" content="webcontent"/>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
   The Body here.
 </h:body>
</html>
```

**Do notice**:

1. `<view>` has been deleted.
2. `<head>` and `<body>` are converted to `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` .
3. The `old` namespace is now replaced with a `new` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

these aren't simple text replacements (you will need to add new namespaces to your files, i.e. the `composition` namespace from Facelets, file extensions change from being .JSP to be .XHTML, etc.), the easier option seems to be XSLT as you would be able to use some kind of logic in it, however, the changes needed to really use Facelets won't be an easy task for any automated process.

Don't waste too much time writing the *state-of-the-art JSF migrator* to achieve this, try to do something that can make almost all changes with minimal effort and then perform modifications by hand to make everything work. If you want to use features from Facelets as templating and composite components then you'll end up restructuring your code by hand anyway.

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be DOM. Manipulate document and save it as a new file (or overwrite). That would be only couple of rules that you could apply recursively for all your document.